# can i import 3d image in my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, 3d

i m new to iphone/ipad application development, can we import 3d image in my iphone/ipad 
app. or there any other controls available to display 3d image. i also want to give actions 
to image on particular sections. can any one help me.

Thanks...

Comment: I think I don't understand your question. What do you mean by 3D image? The iphone or ipad can not display 3d images.

Comment: It can display anything if you define the understanding of the data to be displayed.

Comment: Well, I meant that it wont display it in a 3D manner, because it lacks the hardware,

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to achieve? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. Check out OpenGL samples for iOS. Just google and you will find many.